# Override CSS class coming from DateTimePicker NPM package in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to override a style coming from a NPM packages's CSS?

Im using the DateTimePicker NPM package but having trouble removing the black border from it.

My code is;

```
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker'
import 'react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'

const Calendar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Controller
                control={control}
                name='start_time'
                defaultValue={new Date()}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        onChange={onChange}
                        value={value ? new Date(value) : null}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In the `DateTimePicker.css` file there is a class;

```
.react-datetime-picker__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: thin solid gray;
}
```

I just want to change the border to none

Is this possible?

Comment: try using `!important` with the style you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible just add !important next to property you want to override over other CSS

**`border: none !important;`**

```
.react-datetime-picker__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I cant edit the NPM package css though can i?

Comment: Yes if you write !important next to property you want to override over any css even its from any Pacakage

Comment: You can Learn about it here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp